# How to fix mvc error as shown in description

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The index (zero-based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Please ask your question in English!

Answer (score 0):

Your index is either null or larger then the total size of the array (or other collection)